# Start a thread using a method pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, methods, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to develop a thread abstraction (POSIX thread and thread from the Windows API), and I would very much like it to be able to start them with a method pointer, and not a function pointer.

What I would like to do is an abstraction of thread being a class with a pure virtual method "runThread", which would be implanted in the future threaded class.

I don't know yet about the Windows thread, but to start a POSIX thread, you need a function pointer, and not a method pointer.
And I can't manage to find a way to associate a method with an instance so it could work as a function.
I probably just can't find the keywords (and I've been searching a lot), I think it's pretty much what Boost::Bind() does, so it must exist.

Can you help me ?

Comment: It's already been done. See Boost::thread. If this is just an exercise search stackoverflow some more. PS. No you can;t use any C++ functionality the callback must be a extern "C" function. But from there you can call anything.

Answer (score 9):

Don't do this. Use `boost::thread`.

With `boost::thread` you can start threads with any functor of signature `void()`, so you can use `std::mem_fun` and `std::bind1st`, like in

```
struct MyAwesomeThread
{
    void operator()()
    {
        // Do something with the data
    }

    // Add constructors, and perhaps a way to get
    // a result back

private:
    // some data here
};

MyAwesomeThread t(parameters)
boost::thread(std::bind1st(std::mem_fun_ref(&t::operator()), t));
```

EDIT: If you really want to abstract POSIX threads (it is not hard), you can do (I leave you the initialization of the pthread_attr)

```
class thread
{
    virtual void run() = 0; // private method

    static void run_thread_(void* ptr)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<thread*>(ptr)->run();
    }

    pthread_t thread_;
    pthread_attr_t attr_;

public:
    void launch() 
    {
        pthread_create(&thread_, &attr_, &::run_thread_, reinterpret_cast<void*>(this));
    }
};
```

but `boost::thread` is portable, flexible and very simple to use.

Answer (score 2):

You really should use Boost.Thread. But if you can't and the call to start a thread allows you to pass a parameter to your thread function, a common idiom is to have a stand-alone or static member function which casts the parameter to an object pointer. e.g.

```
class Thread {
public:
  void start() { start_thread(_work, this); }  // whatever call starts a thread

  void work() {} // does thread work

private:
  static void _work(void* param) {
    (reinterpret_cast<Thread*>(param))->work();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a C++ API for threading.  Something like boost::thread (which is pretty much the same API that will be in the new C++).  The OS thread API's are generally in C and you simply CAN'T pass non-static member function pointers to them, nor functors (which is what boost::bind creates).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's actually an exercise, and I don't have the right to use anything (not even Boost).
Of course I don't HAVE to do it that way (I only have to develop a thread abstraction), I just would like to : I used SFML thread abstraction once and I just loved it. It's such a sexy way to deal with it.

Ferruccio way seems good !
If the work() method is pure virtual, it can be implemented in any class implementing the thread abstraction... and it would work just fine, right ? (I'm not quite sure if it will, but according to my basic knowledge of C++, I guess it should ?)